# can't passed a vue js unit test made with jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have a vue.JS component in which, when mounted, executes a function getIngredients :

```
mounted() {
   if (this.cocktail) {
     this.getIngredients();
   }
}
```

I have a unit test that won't pass :

```
it('Call getIngredients function when the component is mounted', async () => {
    const getIngredientsMock = jest.fn()
    const wrapper = shallowMount(CocktailCard, {
      propsData: {
        cocktail: {
          idDrink: '1',
          strDrink: 'Mojito',
        }
      },
      methods: {
        getIngredients: getIngredientsMock
      }
    })
    expect(getIngredientsMock).toHaveBeenCalled()
  });
```

I would like to check that the getIngredients function is executed when mounting the component

Error :

```
› Call getIngredients function when the component is mounted
                                                                                                                                                                                       
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                       
    Expected number of calls: >= 1                                                                                                                                                     
    Received number of calls:    0                                                                                                                                                     

      22 |       }
      23 |     })
    > 24 |     expect(getIngredientsMock).toHaveBeenCalled()
         |                                ^
      25 |   });
      26 | })

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/unit/CocktailCard.spec.js:24:32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to spy the method instead.

```
it('Call getIngredients function when the component is mounted', async () => {
  const getIngredientsMock = jest.spyOn(CocktailCard.methods, 'getIngredients')
  const wrapper = shallowMount(CocktailCard, {
    propsData: {
      cocktail: {
        idDrink: '1',
        strDrink: 'Mojito',
      }
    },
  })
  expect(getIngredientsMock).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```